# Hosting static website with AWS S3 + Cloud Front without Route 53

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I have a external domain which I want to use for a static website on aws.

I found a couple of examples using S3 + CloudFront + Route 53
But is it possible to keep the name server of my domain and work with the external nameserver? (**No Route 53?**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible, Route53 isn't mandatory to use CloudFront and S3. You can have CNAME configured in your DNS provider. However, there is a RFC limitation on CNAME restriction for naked/apex domain(as you cannot have a CNAME record and another DNS record of a different type) so Route53 provides an alternate record called alias record, as long as your DNS provider provides this feature, you're good to go. e.g: CloudFlare provides CNAME flattening

https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169056-Understand-and-configure-CNAME-Flattening

Amazon Route53 alias:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/resource-record-sets-choosing-alias-non-alias.html